# Azure Storage Account cannot create new or delete directory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have two subscriptions in Azure. In both subscription, a StorageV2 was created with one container.

For one subscription I can create new or delete the whole directory.
[image: Working one]

For the other one I can only delete single file in each directory.
[image: Cannot delete or add directory]

Where can I see which permission was missing?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if "Hierarchical namespace" is enabled on the storage account where you're not able to create a directory.

Ability to create a directory is only supported on the storage account with `Hierarchical namespace` enabled (i.e. Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Storage Accounts).

[image]